# I have a list of several values. I need to understand which of them is parent and which is child. How to do it in Excel?

Tags: excel, csv, jira

I have a list in Excel like this:

[image]

You can see that A01->A0101->A010101, it's a chain where we have parents and children.

I need to create a CSV file, where I can see their parent ID and child ID. Like here:

[image]

The question: How to make it possible in Excel? I have idea how to do it with C#, but I need to do it in Excel.

Which result I would like to see:

1. A01 - ID should be 1
2. A0101 - ID should be 2 | Parent ID - 1
3. A010101 - ID should be 3 | Parent ID - 2

In the columns it will be like this:

1. cell - 1
2. cell - 2 | cell - 1
3. cell - 3 | cell - 2

So, I would like to have list only with 2 columns, where I can see ID of the A01 and the parent ID.

In the link below you can see how it should work if you want to put a CSV file in JIRA.

Link:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-import-issues-with-hierarchy-from-a-csv-into-jira-software-1087512458.html

Comment: Can you include the desired results based on your sample input too? Without that, I would suggest an lookup through `=XLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2),A:A,A:A,"")` assuming headers and your list in column A:A.

Comment: JvdV thanks for the reply, I included more info, and hope it's clear if not, then I will try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using Excel ms365 functions:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=LET(x,A2:A18,y,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),HSTACK(y,XLOOKUP(LEFT(x,LEN(x)-2),x,y,"")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can not make it with this formula. It's saying that: "The first argument of LET must be a valid name". What should I put instead of x and y? Or should it stay like this?

Comment: Perhaps your version of Excel uses the semicolon as argument separator within formulas, as opposed to the comma?

Comment: Jos, thanks, that was the problem. Now everything is working and big thanks to JvdV! :)

Comment: @JosWoolley that is not an Excel version issue, it is down to the system settings - locale, language etc

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, thanks, you're correct, I was using the wrong terminology.