# How to find Child ID?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a List with codes, IDs, Parent IDs and would like also to get Child IDs, but not sure how to do this.

The screenshot is below:

[image]

For example:

- |ID|  |PARENT ID| |CHILD ID|

1. A01       |1|   | |         | 2 |
2. A0101     |2|   |1|         | 3 |
3. A010101   |3|   |2|         | |

I have a formula, which is calculating Parent ID, but I have no idea how to do it for Child ID.

**Formula:** =LET(x;A2:A251;y;SEQUENCE(ROWS(x));HSTACK(y;XLOOKUP(LEFT(x;LEN(x)-2);x;y;"")))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75294856/9758194) previous question, you can simply add the 3rd column as a 3rd parameter in the `HSTACK()` function:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=LET(x,A2:A13,y,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),HSTACK(y,XLOOKUP(LEFT(x,LEN(x)-2),x,y,""),XLOOKUP(x&"??",x,y,"",2)))
```

Here `XLOOKUP(x&"??",x,y,"",2)` will look up the ID for the 1st possible child and would leave it blank if no child is found. It's a wildcard search, hence the use of '??' to mimic any two characters.

---

If you wish to display all direct descendents, try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=LET(x,A2:A13,y,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),HSTACK(y,XLOOKUP(LEFT(x,LEN(x)-2),x,y,""),MAP(x,LAMBDA(z,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(y,LEFT(x,LEN(x)-2)=z,""))))))
```

Comment: Again thanks for your answer JvdV! But what do if they have multiple child ID? Like we have A0101 and children: A010101, A010102, A010103. I'm not sure what to do in this situation then.

Comment: @FredericoEglesias, so what would you like to have displayed? I mentioned the above would just find the next in line. Do you want to find all ID's?

Comment: I would like to display all possible child ID's in the cell CHILD ID, if it's possible.